# How do I get Facebook video URL using android jsoup? "hd_src_no_ratelimit"

Tags: android, download, jsoup

[details](http://hizliresimyukle.com/image/5mvYp)

How do I get Facebook video URL using android jsoup?

Keyword : hd_src_no_ratelimit

Comment: Why do you need to use jsoup for that? Is using Facebook SDK not an option? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/

Comment: Does the Facebook SDK give the video url?

Comment: It seems so, please check their docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/